# Quartz.net double execution - umbraco

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, quartz.net

I have the following code:

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        //JOB - Automatically renew member subscriptions
        IJobDetail subscriptionsJob = JobBuilder.Create<UpdateSubscriptions>().Build();


        ITrigger subscriptionsTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("updateSubscriptions", "updateGroup")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .RepeatForever()
            )
            .Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(subscriptionsJob, subscriptionsTrigger);

    }
}
```

Now, whenever this is run it seems that two threads are actually executing this creating unforeseen issues where the code is executed twice.

I am not sure exactly why this is happening? Can anyone see what i might have done wrong?

It is worth mentioning that this is an umbraco application

**Update**

Please note that my job has the `DisallowConcurrentExecution` attribute:

```
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class UpdateSubscriptions : IJob
{
```

**Update The log**

So ive checked out my log and as expected two worker threads are working on the file:

```
P19484/D2/TDefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3
P166696/D2/TDefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1
```

Comment: Where are you starting Quartz ?

Comment: In my code, I'm using a Wait() after the Start(): _scheduler.Start().Wait(); also I'm deleting the job using CheckExists and DeleteJob (to be sure the job is only registered only once)

Comment: @Jerome2606 i am starting it from the  RegisterEvents : ApplicationEventHandler

Comment: Did you put a try catch block in the job, if an error occurs the job will be repeated. If a job throws an exception, Quartz will typically immediately re-execute it

Comment: Hey guys ive updated my question

Comment: Could `JobScheduler.Start()` be being called more than once?